# How to use constant var in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I have defined a variable as:

```
   DateSecondsOffset Int default as 1
```

in a SQL Server Integration Service project. I use it as constant.

In a task, I have the following SQL to set another var NextDT:

```
  SELECT dateadd(s, max(timestamp), 1) DT from myTable
```

I would like to replace the 1 with DateSecondOffset so that I can change it when needed. Can I just type in the var name there or prefix it with @ or something else?

Comment: Is this one correct? Dts.Variables("DTSecondsOffset").Value to replace 1?

Comment: select dateadd(s, max(timestamp), Dts.Variables("DTSecondsOffset").Value) DT from myTable?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a Script..

```
Dts.Variables("DateSecondOffset").Value
```

If you're referring to it in a field..

```
Scope::DateSecondOffset
```

Replace Scope with your scope which can be found in the "package explorer" tab under variables.

If you're referring to it in a SQL...

> SELECT @DateSecondOffset

Be sure to setup your input/output parameters in a SQL Task and ReadOnly/ReadWrite Variables on a script task.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass package variable as a parameter for SQL task.

You can define do it
- in **"Execute SQL Task Editor"->"Parameter Mapping"** section
- or in **ReadOnlyVariables** options (**ReadWriteVariables** options if you want to be able to change variable value during the task) in the **"Script Task Editor"** window

Then declare variable inside sql query and init it with first parameter:

```
DECLARE @DateSecondsOffset INT
SET @DateSecondsOffset = ?
SELECT dateadd(s, max(timestamp), @DateSecondsOffset ) DT from myTable
```

See [Patrick Index: Passing Variables to and from an SSIS task](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/passing-variables-to-and-from-an-ssis-task/)

Comment: SET @DateSecondsoffset = ? got error. It look like that ? is not right in syntax. I have sqlserver 2005 and MVS 2005

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for referencing a parameter in an Execute SQL task depends on the type of connection you're using.

For example ADO.NET connections you use @ParameterName. For OleDB connections you use ?.

Full details can be found here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx